# How to return the line number of the first occurrence of a text in a file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, text

How to return the line number of the first occurrence of a text in a file in linux? For instance, a file as follows.

```
12:04:56 xxxx
12:06:23 xxxx
12:09:11 xxxx
12:09:13 xxxx
12:10:12 xxxx
```

Can anyone provide a line command which returns 3 if the desire text is "12:09:"?

Comment: `-n` or `--line-number` in `grep` should do the trick

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
awk '/12:06:23/{print NR;exit}' file
```

and with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) :

```
grep -n -m1 "12:06:23" file | cut -d':' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -n` return also the line number of the found match. From there on, you can use a combination of `head` and `cut` to extract just the line number:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep -n "12:09" | head -1 | cut -d":" -f1
```

Comment: @sputnick Actually, so can `grep` itself: `grep -n "12:09" bla.txt | head -1 | cut -d":" -f1`. I just find using `cat` more readable, as you can read the entire flow from left to right.

Comment: @sputnick That's not to say I don't like the `awk` solution, though

Comment: @Mureinik: for left to right readability: `< myfile.txt grep ...`

Comment: OOps, yes, grep not awk. But same idea